# Multipeer Connectivity not working over Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity, ios9

I'm building an app using the Network Connectivity but ran into a strange problem using that framework. The app works great if everyone is on wi-fi. But if a device uses Bluetooth, it is not discoverable and nothing works. The same code should work over wi-fi and Bluetooth as far as what I've read. But why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: @DHEERAJ I'm sure it is on on both devices...